# Nested Foreach won't pass variable back out?

Tags: powershell

I have the following `foreach` block that loops through the results of the results from a `Get-ACL` and print out the Path, Username, Permission, etc. as a CSV report.

The variable `$groups` is defined by another script:

```
. C:\Powershell\Get-LocalGroup.ps1
$groups = Get-LocalGroup -Computername $computerName
```

Here is the main foreach block:

```
foreach ($u in $access.Access) {

    if ($u.IdentityReference -like "$domain") {
        Try {
            [String]$uIdent = $u.IdentityReference
            $displayName = get-aduser $uIdent.split("\")[1] -Properties DisplayName | Select-Object DisplayName
            $user = "$($displayName.DisplayName) ($MUDID)"
        }
        Catch {
            $user = "$($u.IdentityReference) (User not found)"
        }

    }
    elseif ($u.IdentityReference -like "S-*") {
        #PROBLEM STARTS HERE
        write-host "SID"
        foreach ($g in $groups) {
            if ($g.SID -like $u.IdentityReference) {
                Write-Host $u.IdentityReference    
                Write-Host $g.SID
                Write-Host $g.Name
                $userSID = $g.Name

            }
            else {
                $userSID = $u.IdentityReference
            }
        }
        $user = $userSID
        Write-Host "User: $user"
    }
    else {
        $user = $u.IdentityReference
    }
}
```

The code works almost perfectly, except that it seems to refuse to pass the following variable back out of the foreach:

```
$userSID = $g.Name
```

As you can see from this sample Output from the (placed for testing only... I swear) Write-Host events:

```
SID
S-1-5-21-4175155190-227829953-2793635334-1036
S-1-5-21-4175155190-227829953-2793635334-1036
AUK-PH-Distribution-Depart
User: S-1-5-21-4175155190-227829953-2793635334-1036
```

I think the issue is with scoping, but I have never run into this before, so am unsure about how to handle it. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried defining `$userSID` before the foreach?   `#PROBLEM STARTS HERE $userSID = ''`

Comment: Can't say for sure but I highly suspect it went sideways with that first line:if ($u.IdentityReference -like "$domain").  The -like operator does a wildcard match, and unless you include some wildcard character (e.g. "$domain\*" it's going to do an exact match.

Comment: If I define `$userSID = 'test'` before the foreach, it still ends up empty during the output.

Comment: @mjolinor Ahh, that was a sanitizing change. It is a wild card match in my real code.

Comment: `$u.IndentityReference` -> `$u.IdentityReference`. BTW, if you use `Set-StrictMode`, then discovering this kind of errors became easier.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ahh man.... I was so careful to look through those sorts of things before I posted this... :( Thanks!

Comment: Actually, that only solves one bug... The `$userSID = $g.Name` assignment still doesn't make it's way out of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: `$userSID = $g.Name` will only have it effect until you reassign different value: `$userSID = $u.IdentityReference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop effectively returns only evaluation result of the last element in `$Groups`. It is updating `$UserSID` for every group, but also it updates it for the last one.

I presume you would need something like this:

```
$UserSID = $u.IdentityReference
$G = $Groups | where SID -like $u.IdentityReference 
if ($G) {$UserSID = $G.Name}
```

You assign default value in advance. You try to find group with such SID (`$G =...`) and if you find it, you assign its name to your variable.

Comment: I see... That makes sense now that you explain that the foreach is just looping all the way through instead of how I imagined it would. I won't be back at work until Monday, but expect this is probably the right solution. I'll check it out then and mark answered if it does point in the right direction.

Comment: Tested this, and it is working perfectly. Thank you for your assistance.